# firebase-import timing out?

Tags: json, node.js, firebase

I'm using the [firebase-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) tool to upload JSON data to my firebase. I consistently get the following error after trying to upload a JSON file that is ~40MB in size. Any ideas why? The output seems to be intentionally cryptic.

It always happens when the upload is 42% complete, and about that much of the JSON does get successfully uploaded to Firebase.

```
FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: ClientId[------]:ErrorId[5]: Error on incoming message 
Importing [====================                             ] 42% (1610/3865)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:44
function ac(a){try{a()}catch(b){setTimeout(function(){throw b;},Math.floor(0))
                                                            ^
AssertionError: false == true
    at onComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/bin/firebase-import.js:222:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:128:47
    at ac (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:44:20)
    at X (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:128:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:121:291
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:85:276
    at md.h.bc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:86:104)
    at ad.bc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:77:364)
    at Q.Od (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-import/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:75:280)
    at Ec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-i
```

Comment: If something times out, it usually is because the operation is taking too long to complete. You might want to try using firebase-streaming-import, which handles larger payloads better.

Comment: Cross-posted on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this particular error was due to a key path in the JSON exceeding Firebase's maximum key path length, which is 768 characters.